# prove by induction that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^n) = \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have demonstrated by Van-Kampen that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) =\langle[ab] | [ab]^2 =1\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.
Using the next connections: $\mathbb{R}P^n \cong S^n\backslash \{\{x,-x\}: |x|=1\}\cong D^n \backslash\{\{\bar x, -\bar x \}: \bar x \in \partial D^n\}$
we can observe that  $\{\{\bar x, -\bar x \}: \bar x \in \partial D^n\} \cong \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} $, when by the induction assumption, $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. But I don't succeed in **formalizing** the induction step to show that indeed $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^{n})\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb RP^n$ is just $\mathbb RP^{n-1} \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$ where the attaching map is the quotient map $S^{n-1} \to \mathbb RP^{n-1}$. By Van Kampen, this implies (for $n-1\ge 2$) that $\pi_1 \mathbb RP^n \cong \pi_1 \mathbb RP^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JustinYoung , just to make sure I understood you correctly, does  $\mathbb{R}P^n \bigcup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$ means a free product with amalgamation? , If so, may you please explain how to see that $\mathbb{R}P^n  = \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \bigcup_{S^{n-1}} D^n $ ?

Comment: That terminology is usually used for groups, but, yes, this is the corresponding thing for spaces. These days it is usually called a "coproduct", more specifically a "push out". To get rid of the fancy language, your description of $\mathbb RP^n \cong D^n/x\sim -x$ shows that you can write $\mathbb RP^n = A\cup B$ where $A \simeq \mathbb RP^{n-1}$, $B \cong \mathring{D^n}$ and $A\cap B \cong S^{n-1}$. Now apply Van Kampen.

Comment: @JustinYoung Got it, thanks!